# Plotting bar chart from dataframe using subplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to use subplot to plot the two curve. However, my code below returns no bar chart in the subplot

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10,10))
axes[0] = recent_grads[:5].plot.bar(x='Major', y='Income')
axes[1] = recent_grads[167:172].plot.bar(x='Major', y='Income')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the subplots as an argument to the plotting function using `ax=`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10,10))
recent_grads[:5].plot.bar(x='Major', y='Income', ax=axes[0])
recent_grads[167:172].plot.bar(x='Major', y='Income', ax=axes[1)
plt.show()
```